# How to convert string numbers into comma separated integers in java?

Tags: java, string, integer

Can any one give me some predefined methods or user defined methods to convert string numbers(example: 123455) to comma separated integer value (example: 1,23,455).

Comment: Do you mean 1,23,455?  Should it be 123,456 or 1,234,567 or 1,23,45?  The answer is likely to be; use DecimalFormat.

Comment: It would be a benefit if you explain the algorithm where to place commata.

Comment: I don't understand the logic in the comma placement. could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: **comma separated integer value**??? int do not have comma in value.

Comment: first i would like to thank you all for your quick reply. my intention, for example if the string 1234 converts to currency then it will become like $1,234. if string is 123456 then currency format is $1,23,456 . i need this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `123455` is a `String`.

```
String s = 123455;
String s1 = s.substring( 0 , 1 );  // s1 = 1 
String s2 = s.substring( 1 , 3 );  // s2 = 23
String s3 = s.substring( 2 , 7 );  // s3 = 455
s1 = s1 + ',';
s2 = s2 + ',';
s = s1 + s2;   // s is a String equivalent to 1,23,455
```

Now we use `static int parseInt(String str)` method to convert String into integer.This method returns the integer equivalent of the number contained in the `String` specified by `str` using radix 10.

Here you cannot convert `s ---> int` . Since int does not have commas.If you try to convert you will get the  following exception **java.lang.NumberFormatException**

you should use `DecimalFormat` Class.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 11):

```
int someNumber = 123456;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.format(someNumber);
```

Answer (score 3):

use java.text.NumberFormat, this will solve your problem.

Comment: first i would like to thank you all for your quick reply. my intention, for example if the string 1234 converts to currency then it will become like $1,234. if string is 123456 then currency format is $1,23,456 . i need this format.

Comment: @sathish To format a number for a different Locale, specify it in the call to getInstance. `NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH)` so if you want an Indian locale, there might be one for that

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an exact solution for my needs.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Mortgage2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal payment = new BigDecimal("1115.37");
        NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US); 
        double doublePayment = payment.doubleValue();
        String s = n.format(doublePayment);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the DecimalFormat class ([here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)), where you can set easily separator and convert a String to a Number with the method `parse()` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The result you expected that is "to comma separated *integer* value", is in my opinion incorrect. However, if you are just looking for **output representation**, how about these lines of codes shown below? (Note, you can not parse the value return from valueToString to some data type long because it just does not make sense :) )

```
MaskFormatter format = new MaskFormatter("#,##,###");
format.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
System.out.println(format.valueToString(123455));
```